# SendKeys in Powerpoint VBA

Tags: vba, powerpoint

Can anyone pls explain me how to use SendKeys in PowerPoint VBA.

Sub SK()

SendKeys ("%"), True      ' Alt
SendKeys ("H"), True     ' Home Tab
SendKeys ("FC"), True     ' Font Color pallet

End Sub

Answer (score 0):

SendKeys in VBA will look like this, with a string of commands in double quotes. You don't need a separate statement for each command:

```
aShape.Select
SendKeys "+{F10}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}~{DEL}" & PhotoName$ & r & p & "{TAB}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}{UP}{DOWN}{TAB}~", True
```